# Split Int Value into Rows In TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of StartTimes and EndTimes

I want to split these into 1 row per 15 minute increment between each start and end time.

Something like

```
SELECT StartTime, DATEDIFF(mi, StartTime, EndTime) / 15 AS Offset FROM myTable
CROSS APPLY
-- put something in here to split each row into (EndTime - StartTime) / 15 rows
```

I think I can use the SQL OVER function for this...but can't wrap my head around how.

Comment: could you add expected result with some data ?

Answer (score 1):

In a situation where you need to generate rows that don't exist, it can be helpful to create a table of numbers, which simply contains a bunch of rows numbering 1, 2, 3, etc.  For example, this would create a table of numbers from 0 to 99:

```
create table ids ( id int )

declare @id int
set @id = 0
while @id < 100
begin
    insert ids values (@id)
    set @id = @id + 1
end
```

Then building on this table of numbers, it's as simple as joining together with the original table, and limiting based on `id` is less than the number of 15-minute periods being generated:

```
select
  DATEADD(mi, id * 15, StartTime) AS StartTime,
  DATEADD(mi, (id + 1) * 15, StartTime) AS EndTime
from
  MyTable T
join
  ids I on I.id < DATEDIFF(mi, StartTime, EndTime) / 15
```

Note that the above queries are making two assumptions:

- All of your StartTime - EndTime combinations have differences that are exactly divisible by 15.
- None of your StartTime - EndTime pairs traverse a range wider than one hundred 15-minute periods (if so, you just need to make the `ids` table larger).

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/595a9

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a resursive CTE for that to avoid creating an auxiliary table:

```
WITH "CTE"
AS
(
  SELECT "id", "starttime" FROM "data"
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "id", DATEADD( MINUTE, 15, "starttime" )
  FROM "CTE"
  WHERE "starttime" < ( SELECT "endtime" FROM "data" AS D2 WHERE D2."id" = CTE."id" )
)
SELECT * FROM "CTE" 
ORDER BY "ID"
```

See [SQL-Fiddle-Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39346/8/0)!

Above Query also assumes that differences of start- and endtime combination in data-table are divisible by 15.

I have edited the query to work with datetimes which are not exactly divisible by 15 - if your chosen interval of 15 minutes does not fit in last calculated interval, it will be rejected:

```
WITH "CTE"
AS
(
  SELECT "id", "starttime" FROM "data"
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "id", DATEADD( MINUTE, 15, "starttime" )
  FROM "CTE"
  WHERE "starttime" <= ( SELECT DATEADD( MINUTE, -15, "endtime" ) FROM "data" AS D2 WHERE D2."id" = CTE."id" )
)
SELECT * FROM "CTE" 
ORDER BY "ID"
```

If you want to get the last timestamp rejected in your results ( in fiddle-demo `id 2, timestamp "12:00:00"` ) just change `<=` to `<`. This also will be relevant if you are working with half-open-intervals.

See [edited SQL-Fiddle-Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce2e4/1/0)